# Linux script reading an ini file and splitting into variables by a specified character

Tags: linux

I'm stuck in the following task: Lets pretend we have an `.ini` file in a folder. The file contains lines like this:

```
eno1=10.0.0.254/24 
eno2=172.16.4.129/25
eno3=192.168.2.1/25
tun0=10.10.10.1/32
```

I had to choose the biggest subnet mask. So my attempt was:

```
declare -A data
for f in datadir/name

do
    while read line
    do
r=(${line//=/ })

let data[${r[0]}]=${r[1]}

    done < $f
done
```

This is how far i got. (Yeah i know the file named name is not an `.ini` file but a `.txt` since i got problem even with creating an ini file,this teacher didn't even give a file like that for our exam.)
It splits the line until the =, but doesn't want to read the IP number because of the (first) . character.
(Invalid arithmetic operator the error message i got)

If someone could help me and explain how i can make a script for tasks like this i would be really thankful!

Comment: How do you compare IP numbers? What makes one *bigger* than another?

Comment: The subnet mask is the part after the slash. The biggest subnet mask would be the IP address with the largest value after the slash.

Answer (score 1):

Both previously presented solutions operate (and do what they're designed to do); I thought I'd add something left-field as the specifications are fairly loose.

```
$ cat freasy 
eno1=10.0.0.254/24 
eno2=172.16.4.129/25
eno3=192.168.2.1/25
tun0=10.10.10.1/32
```

I'd argue that the biggest subnet mask is the one with the lowest numerical value (holds the most hosts).

```
$ sort -t/ -k2,2nr freasy| tail -n1
eno1=10.0.0.254/24
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `let`. It's for arithmetic.

```
$ help let
let: let arg [arg ...]
    Evaluate arithmetic expressions.

    Evaluate each ARG as an arithmetic expression.
```

Just use straight assignment:

```sh
declare -A data
for f in datadir/name
do
    while read line
    do
        r=(${line//=/ })
        data[${r[0]}]=${r[1]}
    done < $f
done
```

Result:

```
$ declare -p data
declare -A data=([tun0]="10.10.10.1/32" [eno1]="10.0.0.254/24" [eno2]="172.16.4.129/25" [eno3]="192.168.2.1/25" )
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` provides a simple solution to find the max value following the `'/'` that will be orders of magnitude faster than a bash script or Unix pipeline using:

```
awk -F"=|/" '$3 > max { max = $3 } END { print max }' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk -F"=|/" '$3 > max { max = $3 } END { print max }' file
32
```

Above `awk` separates the fields using either `'='` or `'/'` as field separator and then keeps the max of the 3<sup>rd</sup> field `$3` and outputs that value using the `END {...}` rule.

**Bash Solution**

If you did want a bash script solution, then you can isolate the wanted parts of each line using `[[ .. =~ .. ]]` to populate the `BASH_REMATCH` array and then compare `${BASH_REMATCH[3]}` against a `max` variable. The `[[ .. ]]` expression with `=~` considers everything on the right side an Extended Regular Expression and will isolate each grouping (`(...)`) as an element in the array `BASH_REMATCH`, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z "$1" ] && { printf "filename required\n" >&2; exit 1; }

declare -i max=0

while read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ ^(.*)=(.*)/(.*)$ ]]
    ((${BASH_REMATCH[3]} > max)) && max=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
done < "$1"

printf "max: %s\n" "$max"
```

**Using Only POSIX Parameter Expansions**

Using parameter expansion with substring removal supported by POSIX shell (Bourne shell, dash, etc..), you could do:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ -z "$1" ] && { printf "filename required\n" >&2; exit 1; }

max=0

while read line; do
    [ "${line##*/}" -gt "$max" ] && max="${line##*/}"
done < "$1"

printf "max: %s\n" "$max"
```

**Example Use/Output**

After making `yourscript.sh` executable with `chmod +x yourscript.sh`, you would do:

```
$ ./yourscript.sh file
max: 32
```

(same output for both shell script solutions)

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: This seems to be a `bash` programming assignment so utilities might be excluded. If not, one could use `sort -t'/' -k2 -r -n datadir/name | head -1|cut -d'/' -f2`
`

Comment: It was tagged `[linux]` so that tends to cover Linux utilities such as `sort` or `awk`. The only downside to a pipeline instead of a single process, is you spawn a subshell for every utility and pipe. For large files that make a significant efficiency difference.